# sIFR with green background in Safari 4

Tags: sifr

Has anyone seen this before? http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/3388/sifrgreenbg.jpg

I'm using sIFR on a lot of pages and have always tested them to be cross browser compatible. Never seen it acting like this. Now all of a sudden I got a report about sIFR showing up with green background in Safari 4.0.3 on MAC. I checked it myself again in all browsers but I couldnt reproduce this appearance.

wmode and bgcolor are set to transparent and I have no idea where this green background could come from. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This would happen if the browser does not support Flash transparency, but that should no longer be a problem in 2009.

I've seen a few reports about issues with Safari 4 but never had enough follow up to determine an exact problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was informed that the guy who reported this issue could solve it by upgrading the Safari flash player plugin from Adobe to the latest version.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be solved by downloading flash from adobe and installing.. so it's most likely a Safari issue.